# what does 'it' refer to here?

Tags: pronouns

> Watching movies or playing video games for too long during the day may
>   also keep you from getting a good night's sleep. Doing these kinds of
>   activities before going to bed can stimulate your brain too much,
>   making ***it*** more difficult to rest.

What does '***it***' refer to here? Isn't it '***your brain***'?

Comment: It could be anaphoric referring to "your brain". But I think it's a meaningless dummy pronoun filling the subject position. The meaning is that "rest" is more difficult.

Comment: Compare, "It got dark, making it harder to see."  =  Dusk came on, making seeing more difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**it** here refers to the situation. - Making it difficult for you to rest.
Or Making resting more difficult.

**"It"** acts as a [dummy subject](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/dummy-subjects).

Comment: Actually this is a wrong answer

Comment: Still *it* doesn't refer to *you*, otherwise you don't need *for you* anymore. *It* refers to the state of being, the situation or the environment in which something needs to be done but is hard to do so.

Comment: @duc Yes, but the the situation around someone or something, mostly a person. But you are right.

Comment: This is actually the right answer.  "Dummy it" refers to the existential fact, the "situation".

Comment: Yeah in this case it's correct. His answer before edited said *it* refered to *you*, which was obviously wrong.

Comment: On second thought, the answer is still incorrect. If *it* here refers to the situation as a dummy subject, then for the sentence to be correct, it should be "making it hard **for the brain** to rest", because the situation can't rest, can I? I stand my ground again and hold my statement that your answer is still wrong.

Comment: @Duc As I told you **it** refers to the situation around **you**. Look at this example: There was a blizzard and it was hard to see.

Answer (score -3):

*It* here refers to *brain*. You look for hint in the same sentence, try to identify singular noun or compound noun that can be replaced by *it* in the sense that it needs to rest.

All the singular nouns or compound nouns in the sentence are: (the action of) *going to bed* and *brain*. Obviously, the meaning tells you that the brain can't rest if it is stimulated too much by playing video games before going to bed. The action of *going to bed* cannot rest, but here only the *brain* can.

EDIT. The best answer chosen by the asker is actually wrong in this sentence meaning, as I explained in the comment section of his/her answer: if *it* in the example refers to the situation, then the sentence has to be "making it hard for the brain to rest", otherwise you would be saying "making the situation hard to rest", which is meaningless. I am aware of the linguistic phenomenon that sometimes we use *it* or *there* to be a dummy subject to fill the sentence structure, however in this case it doesn't function in the same manner.

I highly recommend that the asker unchecks the other person's answer as the best/correct one in order not for other English learners to be biased towards and acquire inaccurate information.

Comment: You are confused. Rephrase the part "making it more difficult to rest" to "making resting more difficult". It in no way refers to the brain.